# Install Sylius without DEMO data

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, sylius

What is the way to install Sylius without any demo products?
During default installation following official documentation I did not notice any options not to install demo data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow these steps

http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/installation-commands.html

and exclude step about loading sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing. This is the link for the latest release :

https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/configuration/installation-commands.html

**Exclude this step : [Loading sample data](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/configuration/installation-commands.html#loading-sample-data)**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, today (in 2024), the sample data are automatically loaded with the `bin/console sylius:install:database`.

My workaround is to force a fixture-suite that do not exists :

```
bin/console sylius:install:database --fixture-suite=nope
```

then I need to finish the installation

```
bin/console sylius:install:setup
```